# Bash - Delete number of chars in each line depending on string-pos in first line

Tags: bash, awk, sed, parameters

I'd like to delete all columns before the `label_port` column. Unluckily it's always at a different position. I'm looking for a way to count the characters before `label_port` in the first line and then delete this number of chars in each line. Anyone has an idea?

```
|  log_port|local_port|label_port|       mtu|
|   0x10100|         1|         7|      9122|
|   0x10500|         5|         8|      9122|

|  log_port|local_port|slocal|label_port|       mtu|
|   0x10100|         1|     0|         7|      9122|
|   0x10500|         5|     0|         8|      9122|
```

Comment: Are there `TABs` or only blanks in the input?

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '/\|label_port/h;G;:a;s/^.(.*\n).(.*\|label_port)/\1\2/;ta;s/\n.*//' file
```

Make a copy of any line that contains `|label_port`.

Append the copy to every line.

Using pattern matching, remove characters from the start of each line until the appended line matches the start of its line.

Remove the newline and any artefacts.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk 'NR==1{s=index($0,"|label_port")} {print substr($0,s)}' file
|label_port|       mtu|
|         7|      9122|
|         8|      9122|
```

Answer (score 0):

The other `sed`-based answer is very elegant and should be preferred. But as it is tricky (and for completeness), here is a maybe easier to understand `sed` solution.

We can use `sed` to print only the first line, with `|label_port|...` removed, and pipe this to `wc` to count the number of leading characters to remove:

```sh
$ n=$(sed -En '1s/\|label_port\|.*//p' file | wc -m)
```

Then we subtract one because `wc` also counts the final newline character that `sed` adds to its output:

```sh
$ ((n-=1))
```

Finally, we strip the `n` leading characters from all lines:

```sh
$ sed -E "s/.{$n}//" file
|label_port|       mtu|
|         7|      9122|
|         8|      9122|
```

The two last commands can be combined:

```sh
$ sed -E "s/.{$((n-1))}//" file
```

Note that we can do exactly the same in one single `awk` program:

```sh
$ awk 'NR==1{n=match($0,/\|label_port\|/)} {print substr($0,n)}' file
|label_port|       mtu|
|         7|      9122|
|         8|      9122|
```